# How do I pass argument correctly on delete Method?

Tags: angular

I just started learning Angular 3-4 months ago. And right now I'm practicing it and I encountered this problem:"Property 'note' does not exist on type 'NoteComponent'." on my deleteNote(note) method. I am confused its not working since on my service file, I have note as a parameter

HTML file

```js
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let notes of notesData">
            <div class="card card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ notes.title }}</h5>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ notes.description }}</p>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="mx-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                            data-bs-target="#editNotesModal"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="mx-2">
                        <i class="bi bi-trash" (click)="deleteNote(note)"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

TS file

```js
export class NoteComponent {
  

  noteForm!: FormGroup;
  notesData: any;
  noteObj: Note = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: ''
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private noteService: NoteService){
    this.noteForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.fetchAllNotes()
  }

  addNote(){
    const { value } = this.noteForm
    console.log(value);

    this.noteObj.id = '',
    this.noteObj.title = value.title,
    this.noteObj.description = value.description

    this.noteService.addNote(this.noteObj).then((note)=>{
      if(note){
        alert("Note Added Successfully")
      }
    })
    this.noteForm.reset()
  }

  fetchAllNotes(){
    this.noteService.getNotes().subscribe((res: Note[])=>{
      console.log(res)
      this.notesData = res;
    })
  }

  deleteNote(note: Note){
    let delConfirm = confirm('Delete current selected Note?');
    if (delConfirm == true){
      this.noteService.deleteNote(note);
    }
  }
}
```

Service

```js
export class NoteService {

  constructor( private fs: Firestore) { }

  addNote (note: Note){
    note.id = doc(collection(this.fs, 'id')).id
    return addDoc(collection(this.fs, 'Notes'), note)
  }

  getNotes():Observable<Note[]>{
    let notesRef = collection(this.fs, 'Notes')
    return collectionData(notesRef, {idField: 'id'}) as Observable<Note[]>
  }

  deleteNote(note: Note){
    let docRef = doc(collection(this.fs,`Notes/${note.id}`));
    return deleteDoc(docRef)
  }

  updateNote(note: Note, notes: any){
    let docRef = doc(this.fs, `Notes/${note.id}`);
    return updateDoc(docRef, notes)
  }

}
```

Model

```js
export interface Note {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    description: string
}
```

Comment: Probably you mean `notes`, the element that iterate from `notesData` based on the `*ngFor`: `deleteNote(notes)`. While I would suggest to name the `notes` as `note` as it is an `object`. You use noun with plural (`s`) for describing the item with more than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *ngFor loop, you are using the variable 'notes' (***let notes*** of notesData) to assign to each element in the array. Therefore, you cannot pass the variable 'note' into the 'deleteNote' function. You need to pass the variable 'notes' that you've created in ngFor.

```
<i class="bi bi-trash" (click)="deleteNote(notes)"></i>
```